# How to use Atoi function to convert from string to int?

Tags: c, binary, hex, atoi

My end goal is to create 8 character long hexadecimal value based on a 32 unit long binary number that is stored in an array. To do this, I'm trying to break the binary array into 8, 4 unit long strings, and convert each of these strings into an int to evaluate the hexadecimal value of each and put them all together(if that makes any sense).

But when I'm trying to convert the string to an int using "binGroup = atoi(str);" and printing it out, it only gives me this:

```
convert to int: 1011
convert to int: 100
convert to int: 0
convert to int: 0
convert to int: 0
convert to int: 0
convert to int: 0
convert to int: 0
```

as opposed to just printing the "str" directly, in which the values are correct:

```
convert to int: 1011
convert to int: 0100
convert to int: 0000
convert to int: 0000
convert to int: 0000
convert to int: 0000
convert to int: 0000
convert to int: 0000
```

Why does it not print out the correct 4 int long binary number when I convert it to an int value?

Here is my code, thanks in advance for reading my long winded question. Any more efficient ways to finding my solution would also be appreciated.

```
i = 0;
  j = 0;
  int m, binGroup;
  int small[4];
  char str[128];
  while(i < N) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      small[j] = binRep[i + j];
    }
    int index = 0;
    for(m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
      index += snprintf(&str[index],128 - index, "%d", small[m]);
    }
    binGroup = atoi(str);
    printf("convert to int: %d\n", binGroup);
    i += 4;

    /*for(m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
      charSmall[m] = small[m];
      printf("%d", charSmall[m]);
    }*/

  }
```

Comment: What is `binRep`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `int` don't have information about whether leading zeros should be printed or not. If you want to force printing 4 digits, use `%04d`.

Comment: Don't use it, use [`strtoll`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) instead.